# What does it mean when iMessage suddenly stops saying "Delivered"?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I was texting my friend and everything was okay until I took a few minutes to reply to her message and my text suddenly does not say "Delivered" under it. I'm under Wi-Fi and she possibly was too so what could've happened? Was it me or her?

Comment: Hi Stephanie. Welcome to Ask Different. As the answer below states, your phone will not say "delivered" unless it was successfully delivered. Try force-closing the Messages app and reopening.

Answer (score 1):

iMessage will not return a "delivered" message if the message was not delivered to the user.

Here are some situations of iMessage returning different statuses:

**Not delivered** (usually accompanied with a red exclamation): the message could not be sent from your phone due to your network connection

**(no message)**: the message was successfully sent from your phone, but not delivered to the recipient due to the recipient's network connection

**delivered**: the message was successfully sent from your phone *and* delivered to the recipient.